# How to define OneToOne mappings with embedded ids with foreign key constraint on non-primary key field?

Tags: java, hibernate, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following tables:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "villages")
class VillageEntity(
        @EmbeddedId
        val id: VillageEntityId) {

    @Column(name = "map_id")
    val mapId: Int
}

@Embeddable
data class VillageEntityId(@Column(name = "village_id")
                           val villageId: Int,
                           @Column(name = "gameworld_id")
                           val gameworldId: UUID) : Serializable


@Entity
@Table(name = "map_cells")
class MapCellEntity(
        @EmbeddedId
        val id: MapCellEntityId)

@Embeddable
data class MapCellEntityId(val id: Int,
                           @Column(name = "gameworld_id")
                           val gameworldId: UUID) : Serializable
```

I'm trying to add (probably several very similar looking ones) OneToOne relationships to the MapCellEntity. Basically, the villages table should have a foreign key constraint on both gameworld_id and the map_id, referencing map_cells' id and gameworld id. The gameworld ids are in both tables' embedded ids. The map id in the village entity currently isn't.

I don't understand how to tell the OneToOne mapping which fields to use in which tables. The closest I got is:

```
//on referenced side, so in the MapCellEntity:   
 @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "mapCell")
    var village: VillageEntity? = null

//on owning side, so in the VillageEntity:

    @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "id.id", referencedColumnName = "mapId"),
                JoinColumn(name= "id.gameworldId", referencedColumnName = "id.gameworldId")
    )
    var mapCell: MapCellEntity? = null
```

I was hoping referencedColumnName would be the column in the current table (villages), but I guess not. I've tried all kinds of things. How do I do this? I can never really follow Hibernate's logic no matter how much I read about it. All I want it to basically do is, whenever I access the MapEntity:

```
SELECT *
FROM map_cells m
JOIN villages v ON v.map_id = m.id AND v.gameworld_id = m.gameworld_id
```

How do I tell hibernate to generate what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this is the way in my case for the join columns above the mapCell, after a lot more trial and error, random errors, and random fixes:

```
    @JoinColumns(JoinColumn(name = "map_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
                JoinColumn(name= "gameworld_id", referencedColumnName = "gameworld_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    )
```

Produces:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
      --lots of fields
    from
        villages villageent0_ 
    left outer join
        map_cells mapcellent1_ 
            on villageent0_.gameworld_id=mapcellent1_.gameworld_id 
            and villageent0_.map_id=mapcellent1_.id 
    where
        villageent0_.gameworld_id=? 
        and villageent0_.map_id=?
```